# How can I go about accessing a class in a plugin from another plugin

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

I have two plugins:

```
public:
    RevPersist(QWidget *parent = 0);


class PluginA;

class PluginA :
        public QWidget,

        public MyInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "com.rev.PluginA" FILE "plugina.json")
    Q_INTERFACES(MyInterface)

public:
    PluginA(QWidget *parent = 0);
```

---

```
#include "pluginA/plugina.h"

class PluginB;

class PluginB :
        public QWidget,

        public MyInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "com.rev.PluginB" FILE "pluginb.json")
    Q_INTERFACES(MyInterface)

private:
    PluginA *pluginA;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to access PluginA from PluginB. I however, get the following error:

```
../plugina/plugina.cpp: In constructor PluginA::PluginA(QWidget*)’:
../plugina/plugina.cpp:16:20: error: PluginA does not name a type
     pluginA(new PluginA)
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is **pluginb.cpp**:

```
PluginB::PluginB(QWidget *parent) :

    pluginA(new PluginA)

{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(myresources);
```

How can I go about accessing a class in a plugin from another plugin? I have already added plugina as a library into pluginb.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: This is wrong design. You should not access classes from plugin. Instead of this create additional shared library with needed classes and link with it from both plugins.

Comment: The code and the error message that you show us are inconsistent. `../plugina/plugina.cpp:16:20: error: PluginA does not name a type
     pluginA(new PluginA)` <-- this error message refers to code in `plugina.cpp` not `pluginb.cpp`

Comment: Yes you can do so, but in an indirect way. We have a similar design where some plugins and the main app are loosely coupled and share data. We implemented an "information bus" in a way, that the plugins all use the same interface with read/write(QJsonObject) functions. The main app has an message dispatcher which dispatches the messages between everybody. This can be used like a remote procedure call.